# When converting HTML code blocks to Markdown with Pandoc what class do I have to give a DIV which surrounds the code block?

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I have some scraped HTML which I want to convert with Pandoc to HTML. Everything goes swimmingly, only code blocks are not recognised as such in the Markdown output.

The HTML surrounds all code blocks with `div`s marked up with the classes `amber-el` and `amber-pre`. So for example:

```
<div class="amber-el amber-pre">-- | Takes in a list, and throws the list away, and returns zero.
-- best O(n), worst O(n), average O(n)
zero :: [a] -&gt; Integer
zero list = case list of
[] -&gt; 0
_:xs -&gt; zero xs</div>
```

However, Pandoc does not recognise this `div` as a code block. Can I add a class to the `div`, so that Pandoc recognises the code block? Or can a simple (Lua) filter mark these `div`s up as code?

***Note:*** The HTML does **not** use `pre` tags to mark up the code blocks.